# Qt installer framework connect to NextButton

Tags: qt, qt-installer

I try to connect the NextButton of the page TargetDirectory with a function:

```
widget.findChild("NextButton").clicked.connect(this, func);
```

But the problem is that findChild returns 0. I tried

```
widget.findChild("TargetDirectoryLineEdit").textChanged.connect(this, func);
```

and this works. Does anyone know how to catch the clicked signal of the next button?

Thank you.

Comment: Show us more code, because it seems OK for me. Maybe you could access directly to children, and not with widget.findChild().

Comment: BackButton, NextButton, CancelButton etc are child widgets of the  Wizard itself, not part of the pages! So you can't access them the way you are trying. 
TargetDirectoryLineEdit is child of the TargetDirectory page so you can access it using widget.findChild.
I am trying to do a very similar thing but as i don't know how to access NextButton so i am also stuck. I want to disable the NextButton on certain conditions.